# Cookies from GeckoFX to HttpWebRequest. How to?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, gecko

I'm using GeckoFX control to login to site. Now I would like to send HttpWebRequest with these stored cookies.

How to do it?

I tried -> http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2010/07/webbrowser-and-httpwebrequest-cookies.html , but this code doesnt work for me. I'm getting exception on:

```
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(
geckoWebBrowser.Document.Url, 
GetGlobalCookies(geckoWebBrowser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri)
);
```

Here is exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Geckofx-Winforms.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Unfortunately the rest part of exception is in Polish... :P

Comment: Hey there, did you get it to work?